# How to call PackageManager.hasSystemFeature from Android native C++ using JNI?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How do you access PackageManager and related methods (like hasSystemFeature) from C++ in Android?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this recently and pieced together a number of other answers to get it working. Sharing it here in case it helps others.

To use, pass in the application context and feature string you want to check. This should be easily extensible to other PackageManager methods.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_your_cool_application_MainActivity_native_1hasSystemFeature(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject calling_object, jobject main_activity, jstring feature_string) {
    jclass activity_class = env->GetObjectClass(main_activity);

    //context.getPackageManager()
    jmethodID method_id_pm = env->GetMethodID(activity_class, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
    jobject package_manager  = env->CallObjectMethod(main_activity, method_id_pm);
    jclass pm_class = env->GetObjectClass(package_manager);

    //PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()
    jmethodID method_id_feature = env->GetMethodID(pm_class,"hasSystemFeature", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
    jboolean has_feature = env->CallBooleanMethod(package_manager, method_id_feature, feature_string);

    return has_feature;
}
```